# Magento 2.2 : Search Functionality/Layered Navigation on a Custom Product Collection?

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, magento2.2

I use a **custom product collection** which is used on **all category view** pages (basically, instead of using Magento's collection, I wrote my own module with the custom collection to implement a cookie-based vehicle filtering system).

I realize that when using a custom collection, the layered navigation, and main product search functionality does not work. Anytime I click a filter on the navigation, it will just show the custom collection without any changes. And when I type in something in the search box, it gets ignored and does not actually filter any products based on what I searched for.

My question is, how do I extend the search functionality and the layered navigation functionalities to cooperate with my custom collection?

EDIT: Here is my **full** custom product collection code located inside the Block folder in my module (Block/CustomCollection.php):

```
<?php
namespace Company\CustomCollection\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;


class CustomCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{    
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry, 
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Productss'));

            return $this;
    }


    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $car = $objectManager->get('Module\CarData\Save\Custom')->get("selectedcar");
        $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');

        if(!empty($data)) {
        $data = array("Toyota"=>"24",  
            "Honda"=>"25", 
            "Lexus"=>"26" 
             );
        $collection = parent::getLoadedProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('vehicle', array('like' => '%' . $data[$car] . '%'));

        $collection->setPageSize(7); // fetching only 7 products
    } else {
        $collection = parent::getLoadedProductCollection();
        $collection->setPageSize(7); // fetching only 7 products

    }
        return $collection;
    }

}
?>
```

EDIT: Here is my FULLY FUNCTIONAL CustomLayer.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\CustomCollection\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface;

class Layer
{
  public function aroundGetProductCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
  ) {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $car = $objectManager->get('Module\CarData\Save\Custom')->get("selectedcar");
        $result = $proceed();

  if(!empty($data)) {
            $data = array("Toyota"=>"24",  
            "Honda"=>"25", 
            "Lexus"=>"26" 
             );
        $result->addAttributeToFilter('vehicle', array('like' => '%' . $data[$car] . '%'));


} else {
$result->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt' => 1201));
}
    return $result;
  }
}
```

DI.XML

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Company\CustomCollection\Block\CustomCollection" />
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="CustomLayer" type="Company\CustomCollection\Plugin\CustomLayer" />
    </type>
</config>
```

I have literally looked everywhere online, and it seems there is nothing about this. I can't be the only one with this issue. A lot of people utilize their own collections, however, what happens when they need to search or if they need to use the layered navigation filter?!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Why dont you get product collection by using prent::getProductCollection(), then add your custom filtering to it. This way you preserve original functionality.

Comment: Does this replace the need to use ProductCollectionFactory?  How would I go about incorporating parent::getProductCollection into my cookie based filter? Do you have an example of this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid **Object Manager**, this is just an untested example based on your code. This goes inside `YourNamespace\YourModule\Block\CustomCollection.php`. This class also needs to extend `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    Registry $registry, 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $car = $objectManager->get('Module\CarData\Save\Custom')->get("selectedcar");
    $data = array("Toyota"=>"24", 
        "Honda"=>"25", 
        "Lexus"=>"26" 
        );
    $collection = parent::getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('car', array('like' => '%' . $data[$car] . '%'));

    return $collection;
}
```

This code assumes you used DI to overwrite core class. In essence, you can tell Magento to use your class instead of his core wherever it is used. I recommend using a plugin for this instance, but you don't need to bother with it. 
This goes inside YourNamespace\YourModule\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Block\CustomCollection" />
</config>
```

I am unable to test this code at the moment, so it might contain some syntax errors, or the Core class could be wrong.
Here is the reference for DI. [Magento DI](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html)

Comment: Ah, I knew it couldn't be this easy. So I went ahead and executed the code...and I received a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on null in "...app/design/frontend/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/template‌​s/product/list.phtml‌​" So I went into the original list.phtml file, and it looks like I may have screwed myself by using "$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Module\Block\MyProductCollection');
$_productCollection = $blockObj->getProductCollection();" This code basically tells list.phtml to find my module with the modified product collection, and use that

Comment: instead of the original "$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();" because otherwise, I don't know how to tell magento to use my custom cookie-based filtered collection. Any suggestions on how to fix this whole mess up? :/

Comment: @Justin You will need to use DI to overwrite Core Block. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I have read about Dependency Injection...but the concept is a bit confusing to me still. If you don't mind, can you show me an example? That would be great. Not sure where to put the di script (inside the specific block, etc.) thanks

Comment: di.xml goes inside your module, i don't have access to a computer currently so i can't be of more help.

Comment: Also note when if you do this correctly with DI you won't need to edit any templates

Comment: I have incorporated di.xml and turned list.phtml back to default. However, I am getting the "No products match your selection"

Here is my list.phtml
`$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
if ( ! $_productCollection || ! $_productCollection->count()): ?>
  <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?>`

And the CustomCollection.php file in my module
 `$collection = parent::getProductCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('car', array('like' => '%7%'));`

Still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: try to comment out the part which adds filter on block, just to make sure everything else is ok

Comment: maybe no products have car attribute that contains 7 as id

Comment: Even without the filter, I get the same error

Comment: Are you sure you extended the class correctly?

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the current full CustomCollection.php with all of your suggested changes

Comment: It should be
class CustomCollection extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.
Also it looks like you will need to overwrite getLoadedProductCollection instead of getProductCollection

Comment: Ah, yeah. I was looking into it after I posted and found that I extended incorrectly. However, after making some changes (I have once again edited the changes into my original post) and then running "magento setup:di:compile" via ssh ...I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper, array given, called in app/code/Company/CustomCollection/Block/CustomCollection.php on line 24

Comment: Your constructor needs to call parent constructor with all apropriate arguments, i will edit my answer to contain it.

Comment: Ahh, no more errors...and page is loading with productcollection...so that's good. However, I find that you cannot directly add filters to a "getLoadedProductCollection." How do i exactly achieve adding the car filter to a loaded collection? Thanks!!

Comment: How was it functioning before today?

Comment: Before today, I ignored getLoadedProductCollection and modified my list.phtml and directly used getproductcollection. However you advised me to use getloadedproductcollection as that is my default list.phtml. So I went back to default so now everything is getloadedproductcollection

Comment: I'm interested in this part:     $car = $objectManager->get('Module\CarData\Save\Custom')->get("selectedcar");

Comment: As mentioned, I am using a cookie-based vehicle fitment. User will enter their model of car, and it automatically gets saved as a cookie. That line basically retrieves the cookie data to tell the product collection which car, if any selected, they have and filter out all the products based on the car chosen.

Comment: This is not functioning at the moment? It cannot read the value from cookie?

Comment: No, it doesn't. load() doesnt seem like it does anything either. It just loads the full product collection as usual. I even tried
$collection->setPageSize(5); and it is being ignored.

Comment: The cookie part is irrelevant at the moment, because for now...I did not enter my vehicle for test purposes. So the code by default will go to the latter part...after "else" which is the the productcollection with one filter, $collection->setPageSize(5); just to see if it will work. But the collection still displays the default, 16 products

Comment: I will need to setup the project and attempt this myself in order to help you. I will edit the answer when done.

Comment: Now I am wondering is it because of the LoadedProductCollection? Perhaps there is a different way to "Addattributetofilter" or "setpagesize" since the product is already loaded?

Comment: Ahh okay. I am so thankful, you're awesome. If you need any of my current code or anything, let me know

Comment: It just occurred to me that overwrite is not actually working, can you list the module's directory structure. Also is your module activated? You can check this with bin/magento module:status

Comment: Yes, my module is activated. So it's CustomCollection/Block/CustomCollection.php, Controller/Index/Index.php, etc/di.xml, etc/frontend/routes.xml, etc/module.xml, /registration.php

Comment: In my comment there is an extra space after =, this could br the issue if you did not remove it

Comment: Which piece of code?

Comment: DI.xml, after for and before =

Comment: Yes, I modified that and did nothing. I believe the module is connecting to the category product page just fine. I have intentionally created an error by doing this `$collection = parent::getLoafdfgsdedPfguctColsdfalection();` and the category product page loaded with a "We can't find products matching the selection."

Comment: Alright, so a little update here. After some digging, I've realized that you cannot use load(); without clear(); the current loaded product collection first. So I went ahead and added a `$collection->clear();` right after `parent::getLoadedProductCollection();` So now it works as expected. HOWEVER, there are still a couple (maybe minor) issues with this setup. 1.) It seems that when I use "addAttributeToFilter," the page numbers become messed up. It still shows all page numbers..even though there are not that many pages within the filtered collection. Does that make sense? (1)

Comment: Nice. It actually does, as pager is separate block from the actual content, you would need to overwrite it too.

Comment: And the layered navigation when "addAttributeToFilter" is in use...it still displays total number of ALL products...and not total number of FILTERED VEHICLE products. And 2.) the search page...when searching a product, the results display all products and not filtered (2)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Is overwriting the pager same concept as overwriting collection like we did? Do I have to create a whole new module or can I just use the existing module, and just add a file in the block folder "CustomPager.php" and use the same di.xml file to inject?

Comment: You can use existing module. Just note that you need other arguments for the constructor inside this new class. This would be better executed by using a plugin on a correct class, but it is too complicated to be worth it and i can't tell you which class it is without in-depth analysis of the code execution.

Comment: So I found the class Pager and extend "Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" to overwrite. Now not sure how I should start to link the Pager to my custom collection so it acknowledges the new modified collection instead of original collection. Mind pointing me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: I would override setCollection and apply the filter before calling the parent setCollection

Comment: Do I have to modify di.xml like <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" type="Company\CustomCollection\Block\CustomPager" />?

Comment: Just add that below the old one. You could kill two birds with one stone by overriding Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer and it's getProductCollection. Ideally it would be a plugin, but not required.

Comment: Ohh, overriding "Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" and getProductCollection will take care of both the layered navigation and the paging issue?! I should do that then instead of overriding setcollection in pager class. And ah I know, plugin will create a more efficient system...but I'm really just trying to knock out this project asap. In the near future when I have more time, I will consider converting into plugin. But for now, I'm just focused on functionality and getting it to work

Comment: It should do it, i haven't tested it so it is just an educated guess.

Comment: I went ahead and created CustomLayer.php (edited my original post on top to show full code) and used the same format as I did with the CustomCollection.php, and nothing seems to change/override. Perhaps I am not doing it correctly/missing something here?

Comment: You need to call parent::getProductCollection, then add filter to it before returning

Comment: So I did that, and somehow I just can't get Magento to connect the model. So I actually went ahead and set up a plugin for this (codes shown above). Now I am quite confused if I should be using "BeforeGetProductCollection," "AroundGetProductCollection," or "AfterGetProductCollection." The above code I tried uses After, and it seems like it is filtering collection, however pagination and layered navigation is still incorrect

Comment: Update: Omg, so I dug around more and finally figured out most of this mess. I am now down to one last issue. So what I did was create a plugin called CustomLayer (shown above), and basically it replaces the need for "ProductModify" which is now rendered useless pretty much. I transferred the cookie/filter setup that we did on ProductModify onto CustomLayer, using AroundGetProductCollection and it just worked like a charm. The search/page is completely fixed. However! I am still not able to get layered navigation to work :/ The layered navigation still thinks it is a full collection. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean, where is it wrong?

Comment: The layered navigation is wrong. Even though I used `aroundGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer)` the layered navigation still displays full collection without the vehicle filters

Comment: Layered filter count is wrong..

Comment: Any solution guys? I am facing the same solution that "The layered navigation still displays full collection without the vehicle filters".

Comment: Not working I tried all the way !